# Video Encryption Algorithm (VEA) in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to encrypt and decrypt the video by using the "video encryption algorithm (VEA). "
Can you help me to find a description of the algorithm, scheme, and the process of encryption and decryption using the "Microsoft visual studio 2008"
and how to write the listing program in visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Check ICM's MPEG Video Encryption Algorithms publication describing 4 lightweight MPEG encryption algorithms.

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1008859